# Statically linked gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, configure

Is there any method to build statically linked gcc compiler? If yes, what flags of configure/make should I use? I expect getting gcc and g++ binary files
which should be "not a dynamic executable" (while checking with ldd
tool, for example).

Comment: Using the `--static` flag is a good starting point.

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)? You see those `--enable-*` and `--with-*` flags? You know you can reverse them with `--disable-*` and `--without-*` respectively?

Comment: Are you really sure that is what you want? _Why_? Isn't it merely that you want to _use_ gcc to link a static executable?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you for reply. But I've already used it this way: LDFLAGS="-static" ../configure ... But binary file still remains shared object. Is there any difference between one and two dashes?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for reply. As I've understood, this flags means to **build** static libraries, but not to make a nonshared executable.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for reply. No, Im sure that I want /bin/gcc as a non dynamic executable.

Comment: Disabling all shared options is a good start. Then using e.g. `--with-stage1-ldflags` and `--with-boot-ldflags` to set linker flags to link statically could be used.

Comment: Ok, as you like, whyever. Though I would assume that you want `/usr/local/bin/gcc` as a statically linked executable, not `/bin/gcc` ;-) Or _maybe_ `/usr/bin/gcc`, though that looks like a bad idea...

Comment: @arkascha of course, of course. Maybe bad, but I need It. Well, it is not good, to ask another question within first... But, is it possible to tell bash to link gcc dynamically against special libc.so and libstdc++.so? For example, this libs are in my home dir. LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems not working...

Comment: Sure that is possible, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` definitely works, or you can specify the absolute path to the library. Again I ask myself why one wants to do that, though... Note however that you need to set the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when _using_ the dynamically linked executable, not only at compilation time.

Comment: @arkascha but even if I export LD_LIBRARY_PATH g++ output is "/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by g++)". Don't know why, but it seems that he stops at this libs and does not go to LD_LIBRARY_PATH...

Comment: Nothing we can say with those tiny information chips. Please open a separate question and describe the full setup, including paths, libraries and commands.

Comment: @arkascha I need to wait 90 minutes before another question.

Comment: Yes, that may well be the case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thaks a lot! It worked! Can you put it into answer? Here is used configure flags: ../configure --prefix=/home/myuser/soft/gcc-6.2.0/myusr/ --enable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-shared --disable-host-shared --with-boot-ldflags=-static --with-stage1-ldflags=-static

Comment: @arkascha I've got an answer, but may be it is not the best decision for my purpose. Here is a link to a separate question with full setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101950/run-g-linking-to-special-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Disabling all shared options is a good start. Then using e.g. `--with-stage1-ldflags` and `--with-boot-ldflags` to set linker flags to link statically could be used.
                    – Some programmer dude

It worked! Here is used configure flags:

```
../configure --prefix=/home/myuser/soft/gcc-6.2.0/myusr/ --enable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-shared --disable-host-shared --with-boot-ldflags=-static --with-stage1-ldflags=-static
```

– AccumPlus